# How to send data with two names and only one field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I have that form:

```
 <div id="login">
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="[SITE_URL]/wp-login.php" method="post">
<label>Login:<input type="text" name="log" name="pwd" id="log" value="" size="20" tabindex="1" /></label>

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login &raquo;" tabindex="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="lector/" />

</form>
</div>
```

I would like the user only to fill the "login" field and when submit, the data introduced in that field will be sent with the name "log" and "pwd". Because the password is exactly the same as the user, so this will allow to login wothout having to write the same twice.

Thanks!

Comment: Why to have password then ? just use login. Security level would be the same.

Comment: If anything `name="log" name="pwd"` would not work, `name="log pwd"` may possibly, if not then you simply duplicate the `$_POST['pwd']` variable in the php page where the form submits to `$_REQUEST['log'] = $_POST['pwd'];`

Comment: Thats only for users that have the same field data for password and usernames, wordpress requieres that. If I delete in the hole site the password, then anyone could put admin and delete mi site.

Comment: I've tried name="log" name="pwd" and name="log pwd" before, but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can't use two "name" in one  tag. You can use one name and create 2 variables in the php form with the same name. Something like,

```
$log = &_POST["pwd"];
$log2 = &_POST["pwd"];
```

Another way to do that, you can add a

```
<input type="hidden">
```

tag and make the value changeable via javascript with the 1st input.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to copy input to another hidden field onsubmit:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://catalunyalliure.cat/wp-login.php" method="post" onsubmit="this.pwd.value=this.log.value;">

<label>Login:<input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="" size="20" tabindex="1" /></label>
<input type="hidden" name="log" id="log" value="" />
```

Comment: But the value for the hidden field has to be the "log" one, and that's what exactly I'm searching for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not english and I'm an student. Could you tell me more in detail what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Although, that seams a bit weird to me, you can do it by handling it on the server side.

```
<input type="text" name="log-pwd" ...
```

And in your PHP, you just use:

```
$_POST["log-pwd"];
```

**Second option:**

```
<input type="text" name="pwd" ...
```

And in your PHP, you just use:

```
$username = $_POST["pwd"];
$password = $_POST["pwd"];
```

Comment: I need to have the "pwd" because other users need to login in other page with the password. I want only in that form to duplicate the data filled up in the "log" field to the "pwd" field.

Comment: But the problem is that I have other users with password. It should be like a javascript code to copy the data from one field to another. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer to the problem!

```
    <div id="login">
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="[SITE_URL]/wp-login.php" method="post">
<label>Login:<input type="text" name="log" value="" size="20" tabindex="1" id="log" /></label>
<input type="text" name="pwd" value="" id="pwd" />

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login &raquo;" tabindex="3" onclick="populateDisplayName()" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="lector/" />

</form>
</div>

<script>
function populateDisplayName(){
    var Log = document.getElementById('log');
    document.getElementById('pwd').value = log.value;
}
</script>
```